# What's the best strategy to monitor Splunk log for missing event successful?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have two different events ie., **started** and **successful**. The **successful** might not be an happening event after **started** then, considering this case, is the below search criteria correct?

```
index=a source=b 
| transaction startswith=MIT="Local Step started." endswith=MIT="Copy step successful." keepevicted=true 
| search closed_txn=0
```

Comment: what is your unique connection between the 'start' and 'successful' events?

Comment: I have to consider only this scenario where once started event is done the other event successful will not be done then is the usage of the above criteria correct?

Comment: Are events only ever serially-recorded? Ie, you can *never* have one event start, then another, then another, then the second end, then the third, then another start, then the first end, etc? If you cannot be 100% certain events are only ever sequential, you *must* have some way to identify what an "event" is in this context. Otherwise you won't be `transaction`ing correctly. What does your data actually look like? There is most likely a much faster way to get what you're looking for by using `stats`, but we need to see some sample data to help you.

Comment: In my splunk log i have only STR=20230425 05:23:10.880|MIT=Local Step started. but not  STR=20230425 05:23:17.980|MIT=Copy Step successful.

Answer (score 0):

Given the small sample you gave us, this should do what you're looking for (without using `transaction`):

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp STR=* (MIT="Local Step started" OR MIT="Copy Step successful")
| eval status=if(match(MIT,"started"),"begin","end")
| stats values(status) as status by STR
| where mvcount(status)<2
```

What this does:

- only look for entries where there is a `STR` values, *and* `MIT` is equal to "Local Step started" OR "Copy Step successful"
- because we know `MIT` only ever contains "Local Step started" OR "Copy Step successful", set `status` to "begin" if "started" is found, and "end" otherwise
- [`stats values(status)`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/stats), grouping by `STR`
- filter all the `values()`'d entries by only those that have *one* entry (either a "begin" or an "end")

The result *should* be all `STR`s for which there was no successful completion